# SecondaryNameNode Error - Lock on /app/hadoop/tmp/dfs/namesecondary/in_use.lock acquired by nodename

Tags: hadoop

I'm just starting with Hadoop, facing issues in starting SecondaryNameNode(SNN). I could see below error from the logs

**Error:** 
2015-10-28 00:26:58,495 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage: Lock on /app/hadoop/tmp/dfs/namesecondary/in_use.lock acquired by nodename 10496@sam-Notebook

Below are my conf files, is this because both NameNode and SNN tries to access/use same tmp directory?

**hdfs-site.xml**

```
<configuration>
<property>
  <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
  <value>file:/home/sam/hadoop/dfs/data/</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
  <value>file:/home/sam/hadoop/dfs/name/</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>dfs.replication</name>
  <value>1</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

**mapred-site.xml**

```
<configuration>
<property>
  <name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
  <value>localhost:9001</value>
  <!-- <value>localhost:54311</value> --> 
</property>
</configuration>
```

**core-site.xml**

```
<configuration>
<property>
  <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
  <value>/app/hadoop/tmp</value>
  <description>A base for other temporary directories.</description>
 </property>

<property>
  <name>fs.default.name</name>
  <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

PS: I used [article](http://www.bogotobogo.com/Hadoop/BigData_hadoop_Install_on_ubuntu_single_node_cluster.php) as a reference to install hadoop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

over looked, the actual error was "2015-10-27 23:34:21,320 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SecondaryNameNode: Exception in doCheckpoint java.io.IOException: Inconsistent checkpoint fields." To fix it, delete the namesecondary directory under /app/hadoop/tmp/dfs and restarted hadoop